# Duda consulta SQL Oracle - Saldos diarios

Tags: oracle, sql

Obtengo la siguiente tabla mediante el `query`

```
SELECT S.cuenta,M.fecha periodo,M.IMPORTE neto_periodo,S.Saldo_inicial
FROM Saldos
INNER JOIN (
           SELECT MOV.cuenta,
                  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('19570101','YYYYMMDD') + MOV.fecha_relativa,'YYYYMMDD') fecha,
                  SUM(MOV.NUM_IMPOR * ((debito_credito * 2) - 3)) IMPORTE
           FROM movimientos MOV
           WHERE fecha_relativa BETWEEN 22857 AND 22878
           GROUP BY MOV.tipo,
                    MOV.DCO_MONED,
                    MOV.KEY_PCCTA,
                    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('19570101','YYYYMMDD') + MOV.RFE_IMPUT,'YYYYMMDD')
) M ON M.cuenta = S.cuenta
```

Obtengo la tabla (filtrada por una cuenta)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es calcular el saldo diario para luego calcular el promedio del mes arrastrando el saldo a los días faltantes como sigue

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así hacer un promedio del campo saldo, pero no se me ocurre cómo, les agradecería la ayuda.

Saludos.